# Is there a way to perform a "Submit" function outside of the website?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to click on a button on the Amazon website from outside of the website.

For Example: At the bottom of every product review is a "Helpful" button. If a review was helpful, the reader/shopper can click this button to let the reviewer (and Amazon) know that the review was helpful. (It's basically a "Like" button).

What I'm trying to accomplish:
I want to post my reviews on my own website/blog and still obtain "Likes" without asking readers to click a link to a product page, then search for my review, then click the button.

Comment: Javascript on one domain is not allowed to access information on another domain.  Such an interaction would have to go through a proxy of some kind.  However, a proxy in this case would not be able to apply a "like" specific to your visitor, unless you had their amazon information.  Which I assume you do not have.

Comment: You can look into Chrome extension development for this kind of task. All your users will have to install the extension on their browsers. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to do what you have in mind.

JavaScript can generally access information on another domain except if specifically configured in the origin website through [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Unless you own amazon.com, you won't be able to configure amazon's CORS headers to make them accessible to some JS running on your website.

You can however, from your website front-end, make a request to your website back-end that would be able to access amazon's data just like your browser does. Using a browser emulator like [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer), you'll be able to launch an amazon page and programmatically retrieve infos, click on things and do other stuff.

However, the page that Puppeteer will be able to spin up will include credentials (cookies, localstorage content, auth token, etc) provided by your server, so Puppeteer will not see the same amazon.com your user sees on his browser, unless your user agrees to give you its amazon credentials, and at this point I'm pretty sure no user would do that, and that would not be authorized by amazon's terms of services.

TL;DR even if what you have in mind is not *impossible*, it would weeks for your and your team to code a system that would potentially allow you to do that, and that's provided the law is on your side, which is probably not the case.